# How to prevent a react webpage from scrolling up when a component gets focus?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When I scroll completlely to the bottom of my page and click anywhere inside my modal, the page will scroll up a little. When I click on a link, it will sometime scroll up inseat of going to the link's address.

How can I prevent this? Thank  you

Comment: insert your code here

Comment: This is not a react thing, if you set the focus of an element then the browser will show that element when it's outside scrollable content.

Comment: Can you submit your code? I think you either redirecting to the same page or your event handler is conflicting. I am assuming that you are using React Router.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Window.scroll()` to get and set your scroll position. If you post the code, I can help you better.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll